# LINQ - How to Flatten List<List<string>> where strings are pipe-delimited

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<List<string>>` in C# as below (output from Immediate window):-

```
macthedList Count = 2  
macthedList[0]  
    [0]: "Rob"  
    [1]: "23"  
    [2]: "Math"  
    [3]: "98"  
macthedList[1]  
    [0]: "Jim"  
    [1]: "25"  
    [2]: "Science|Math|LA"
    [3]: "92|99|89"
```

I would like to flatten the above to get a list of 4 lists like below:-

```
macthedList Count = 4  
macthedList[0]  
    [0]: "Rob"  
    [1]: "23"  
    [2]: "Math"  
    [3]: "98"  
macthedList[1]  
    [0]: "Jim"  
    [1]: "25"  
    [2]: "Science"  
    [3]: "92"  
macthedList[2]  
    [0]: "Jim"  
    [1]: "25" 
    [2]: "Math"  
    [3]: "99"  
macthedList[3]  
    [0]: "Jim"  
    [1]: "25"  
    [2]: "LA"  
    [3]: "89"
```

Can you please show me how do I do it using `LINQ`?  I guess we use 'SelectMany' but not entirely sure how.

Comment: You might be able to write some convoluted Linq to do this, but two dozen or so lines of well-chosen C# code, String.Split and String.Join will get you there faster and probably run more efficiently.

Comment: You'd be better off if you just created a class to hold these values that included a list of the class/score pairs as another class type or tuples if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the pure Linq code for that

```
var result = source.SelectMany(
    x => x[2].Split('|')
        .Zip(x[3].Split('|'), (c, s) => new { Course = c, Score = s })
        .Select(cs => new List<string> { x[0], x[1], cs.Course, cs.Score}))
    .ToList();
```

Note that if the number of pipes in the 3rd and 4th strings of the sub-lists do not match up this would result in the shorter of the two.  It also will throw if any of the sub-lists do not have at least 4 items.

Comment: Elegant use of Zip! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This solution solves the specific case you've outlined (disregarding any exceptions to the logic) using `SelectMany()`, although it's not necessarily pretty:

```
var matchedList = new List<List<string>> {
    new List<string> { "Rob", "23", "Math", "98" },
    new List<string> { "Jim", "25", "Science|Math|LA", "92|99|89" }
};

List<List<string>> flattened = matchedList.SelectMany(s =>
{
    var courses = s[2].Split('|');
    var grades = s[3].Split('|');
    return courses.Select((c, index) => new List<string> { s[0], s[1], c, grades[index] });
}).ToList();
```

As others have mentioned, if you want this code to be maintainable, readable, testable, and generally decent you should consider translating these lists into well defined objects that encapsulate this logic.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Agreed, this a good candidate for objects. I'll look into this further.

Answer (score 0):

```
var source = new List<List<string>> {
    new List<string> { "Rob", "23", "Math", "98" },
    new List<string> { "Jim", "25", "Science|Math|LA", "92|99|89" }
};

var result = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (var list in source)
{
    var name = list[0];
    var age = list[1];

    var courses = list[2].Split('|');
    var scores = list[3].Split('|');

    for (int i = 0; i < courses.Length; i++)
    {
        var temp = new List<string>();

        temp.Add(name);
        temp.Add(age);
        temp.Add(courses[i]);
        temp.Add(scores[i]);

        result.Add(temp);
    }
}
            
foreach (var list in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
}
```

Comment: This of course relies on `scores` having at least the number of items as `courses` or it will throw an exception.

Comment: @juharr Yes, number of courses and scores are equal.